# Выбор поля в запросе в зависмости от значения

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть четыре поля a, b, price и sum. Мне нужно автоматом заполнить sum, но так чтобы price умножалась на меньшее из полей. Как составить такое условие? Спасибо!

Comment: Вы поставили теги php и mysql - ваш вопрос касается того, как это сделать в языке php или как это сделать в SQL-запросе mysql ? В MySQL есть функция `least()`, например

Comment: Да, интересует еще mysql вариант. То есть будет выглядеть так: UPDATE goods SET sum = price * least(a,b); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `sum` = `price` * LEAST(`a`, `b`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Что бы найти наименьшее значение вам поможет функция `min`
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.min.php

```
$sum = $price*min($a,$b);
```